# Ipv4 прокси перестают работать через 30-40 секунд работы

Tags: ubuntu, ip, proxy

Поднял прокси на 3proxy, помогли добрый люди со стэка, но появилась существенная проблема, связанная с тем, что прокси перестают работать буквально через 30-40 секунд. Конфиги:

Часть конфига /etc/network/interfaces (всего 256 прокси):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.215.111.29
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 95.215.111.1
        pointopoint 95.215.111.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

up ip addr add 185.187.198.0/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.0/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.1/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.1/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.2/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.2/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.3/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.3/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.4/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.4/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.5/24 dev eth0
down ip addr del 185.187.198.5/24 dev eth0
```

Далее часть 3proxy.cfg:

```
pidfile /usr/local/etc/3proxy/3proxy.pid
maxconn 10000
nscache 65536
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
daemon
setgid 65535
setuid 65535
flush

proxy -n -a -p8000 -i185.187.198.0 -e185.187.198.0
proxy -n -a -p8001 -i185.187.198.1 -e185.187.198.1
proxy -n -a -p8002 -i185.187.198.2 -e185.187.198.2
proxy -n -a -p8003 -i185.187.198.3 -e185.187.198.3
proxy -n -a -p8004 -i185.187.198.4 -e185.187.198.4
proxy -n -a -p8005 -i185.187.198.5 -e185.187.198.5
proxy -n -a -p8006 -i185.187.198.6 -e185.187.198.6
proxy -n -a -p8007 -i185.187.198.7 -e185.187.198.7
proxy -n -a -p8008 -i185.187.198.8 -e185.187.198.8
proxy -n -a -p8009 -i185.187.198.9 -e185.187.198.9
proxy -n -a -p8010 -i185.187.198.10 -e185.187.198.10
proxy -n -a -p8011 -i185.187.198.11 -e185.187.198.11
proxy -n -a -p8012 -i185.187.198.12 -e185.187.198.12
proxy -n -a -p8013 -i185.187.198.13 -e185.187.198.13
proxy -n -a -p8014 -i185.187.198.14 -e185.187.198.14
proxy -n -a -p8015 -i185.187.198.15 -e185.187.198.15
proxy -n -a -p8016 -i185.187.198.16 -e185.187.198.16
proxy -n -a -p8017 -i185.187.198.17 -e185.187.198.17
proxy -n -a -p8018 -i185.187.198.18 -e185.187.198.18
proxy -n -a -p8019 -i185.187.198.19 -e185.187.198.19
proxy -n -a -p8020 -i185.187.198.20 -e185.187.198.20
```

Вывод ip a:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:57:95:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 95.215.111.29 peer 95.215.111.1/32 brd 95.215.111.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.0/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.1/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.2/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.3/24 scope global secondary eth0
```

Адреса весят на интерфейсе, похоже проблема в самом прокси-сервере, но не знаю конкретно в чем